# How to globalize translate pipe of ngx-translate?

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, ngx-translate

I'm using `ngx-translate` package to internationalize my angular application. translating text using translate pipe like this

```
{{ 'title' | translate }}
```

The problem is when I try to use this pipe in others module of the application it gets error. the pipe translate could not found

I tried to use `SharedModule` to solve the problem and it's working but, I think it's annoying to always use SharedModule only for translate when there are a lot of modules to use translate

Is there any way to globalize the translate pipe?
So that I can use translate from any component of module

Comment: There no others way for a `another module` to see the ` translate pipe` unless you import the `module` which declares and exports that `pipe`

Answer (score 1):

Your main module need to import `TranslateModule.forRoot(transLoader)` or you can make separate module like bellow and import it to your main module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FirestoreTranslateLoader } from "./firestore-translate-loader";

export function AngularFireFactory(db: AngularFirestore) {
  return new FirestoreTranslateLoader(db);
}

const transLoader = {
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: AngularFireFactory,
    deps: [AngularFirestore]
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(transLoader),
  ],
})
export class TranslModule { }
```

All child modules need to import: `TranslateModule` with no calling `.forRoot()`. Or like bellow stick it to `SharedModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And about my factory loader if you need to download translation from firebase:

```
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

export class FirestoreTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }
    getTranslation(lang: string, prefix: string = 'langs'): Observable<any> {
        return this.db.doc(prefix + '/' + lang).valueChanges() as Observable<any>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, it will work, or you can import the TranslateModule in the imports of decorator in component.ts, if standalone is true

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
     loader: {
     provide: TranslateLoader,
     useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
     deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```